# rails, getting bootstrap's typeahead to work with rails and jquery (which work normally)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, typeahead

i was wondering if someone could help with me bootstraps "typeahead" with rails and jquery autocomplete

in my 'new' action template, i have...

```
        <div class="tags">
            <%= f.label :tag_names, "Tags" %>
            <%= f.text_field :tag_names,
                data: { autocomplete_source: tags_path} %>
        </div>
```

which then goes to my index action of my tags controller

```
    def index
       @tags = Tag.order(:name).where("name like ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")
       render json: @tags.map{ |tag| {:label => "#{tag.name} x #{tag.count}", :value => tag.name} }
    end
```

and below is my jquery ui autocomplete code, though i dont think its very necessary here...but here it is incase

```
  $(function() {
  var extractLast, split;
  split = function(val) {
    return val.split(/,\s*/);
  };
  extractLast = function(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
  };
  return $("#lesson_tag_names").bind("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB && $(this).data("autocomplete").menu.active) {
      return event.preventDefault();
    }
  }).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
      return $.getJSON($("#lesson_tag_names").data("autocomplete-source"), {
        term: extractLast(request.term)
      }, response);
    },
    search: function() {
      var term;
      term = extractLast(this.value);
      if (term.length < 1) {
        return false;
      }
    },
    focus: function() {
      return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
      var terms;
      terms = split(this.value);
      terms.pop();
      terms.push(ui.item.value);
      terms.push("");
      this.value = terms.join(", ");
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

the autocomplete works, however i can't seem to get it to work with twitters bootstrap.
i tried providing

```
data: { autocomplete_source: tags_path, provide: "typeahead"} %>
```

and

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead()
```

into my application.js file. but it doesn't seem to work. i also tried giving my form an id attribute with...

```
                <%= f.text_field :tag_names, id: "autocomplete",
                data: { autocomplete_source: tags_path} %>
```

so i can do something like

```
    $('#autocomplete').typeahead()
```

however by giving my form an :id attribute, my autocomplete stops working. so...im not really sure what is wrong. are there other ways of doing it?

help would be much appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue and ended up styling the jQuery UI autocomplete like the bootstrap typeahead (basically applying bootstrap CSS to jQuery UI elements).

How I did it: 
http://criticalthinking.tumblr.com/post/17940560421/making-jquery-ui-look-like-bootstrap

Comment: oh neat, did you ever find a way to get the letters being bolded as someone types?

Comment: @Crystal.. hadn't tried - but I think that it would probably require some custom JS..

Comment: hmmm i guess ill just leave off the bolding. its not working for me haha. thank you for answering and sending that helpful link = )